# Bind variables from Command line to test groovy Script

Tags: java, binding, groovy, command-line-interface

I have a groovy script used in conjunction with GroovyScriptEngine:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GroovyScriptEngine gse = new GroovyScriptEngine(new String[] {"/home/user/tmp"});
    Binding varSet = new Binding();
    varSet.setVariable("testVar", "Hello World");
    gse.run("printHello.groovy", varSet);
}
```

This is running just fine from java. The printHello.groovy starts keeping as already defined all the bound variables. The script "/home/user/tmp/printHello.groovy" is something like this:

```
println("${testVar} !!!")
```

What I want is to be able to test this script calling it from command line, but I haven't found a way to pass the binding variables to my script.

$ groovy printHello.groovy [???]

That could be very useful for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass the arguments You need after the script invocation:

```
$ groovy groovyAuthDefault.groovy user pass
```

In the script all the parameters are accessible via `args` variable. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367384/how-to-capture-arguments-passed-to-a-groovy-script).

Is that what You were looking for?

**UPDATE**

Found solution but it has some limitations, maybe it's possible to bypass them but don't know exactly how. 
As I wrote above when You invoke script from command line You can pass arguments that are kept in `args` list. The problem lies in the fact that `GroovyScriptEngine` doesn't invoke the external script with it's *main* method - there's no `args` list so it fails with an `MissingPropertyException`. The idea is to set fake `args`.

**java**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GroovyScriptEngine gse = new GroovyScriptEngine(new String[] {"/home/user/tmp"});
    Binding varSet = new Binding();
    varSet.setVariable("testVar", "Hello World");
    varSet.setVariable("args", null); //null, empty string, whatever evaluates to false in groovy
    gse.run("printHello.groovy", varSet);
}
```

**printHello.groovy**:

```
if(args) {
    setBinding(new Binding(Eval.me(args[0])))
}
println("${testVar} !!!")
```

In *printHello.groovy* `args` is checked. If it evaluates to true it means that script was invoked from command line with arguments and a new `Binding` is set - evaluated from first element of arguments passed (plain groovy script extends `groovy.lang.Script`. If `args` evaluates to false it means that script was run with `GroovyScriptEngine`.

Command line invocation:

```
groovy printHello.groovy [testVar:\'hi\']
```

Exception handling might be added with other improvements as well. Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry Opal, maybe that's the only answer but I expected to find a real command line way to bind variables. The script does not define in any way these variables, even through args[], it simply knows about them trough Binding.

Binding is used in my web app to bind some objects and let them to be managed by a dynamically loaded groovy script. A very similar but, as far as I know,not the same thing as using args. 

And if I decide to use args for testing the script, what can be the way I use args with GroovyScriptEngine ?

Comment: Can You provide a minimal working example just to know exactly how it works? It seems that something like `JCommander` or `CliBuilder` might be needed.

Comment: I edit the original question in order to appear minimal and easily reproducible. You must have the groovy embeddable jars in your class path to compile it.

Comment: That's a viable way. The script must take into account both ways of being executed. I thought about that already but I hoped for a faster emulation of binding. Anyway your example is pretty clear and adoptable. Thanks.