# Using parameters in a groovy script

Tags: groovy

Just starting with groovy, be grateful if someone could help me out.

I'm writing a function in a script that will accept a parameter.

```
def print_arg(def arg){
    println "$arg"
}
```

I save that file as test.groovy.

How do I test throwing arguments at the function from the command line?

```
groovy test.groovy print_arg input
groovy test.groovy print_arg 'input'
groovy test.groovy print_arg(input)
```

None of the above work

I suspect I'm doing something fundamentally daft :-)

Any tips, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the way to  call a method from script

```
def print_arg(def arg){
    println "$arg"
}

print_arg ("hello")
```

Scripts receive `args` array so following will pass argument to your function

```
def print_arg(def arg){
        println "$arg"
    }

print_arg (args[0])
```

(There are more elegant mechanisms that you can pick later  [How to capture arguments passed to a Groovy script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367384/how-to-capture-arguments-passed-to-a-groovy-script) - my answer is from above link, could not duplicate as this question is more basic)

Comment: Thanks Jayan, you are an absolute gent